# Route entire subnet via network interface in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to route a whole subnet through an EC2 instance.

I have an EC2 instance which is part of subnet A.

I have created a Route Table entry which sets the network interface of that instance as the target point for the whole subnet.

However, I don't get traffic on that interface for any other IP other than the one that is allocated to that network interface from other subnets, while I was expecting that all of IP's part of subnet A would be routed via that network interface to other subnets.

Is there a way to route a whole subnet via a network interface? The end goal is to have an instance as a gateway for all traffic towards a given subnet.

Comment: Did you disable the source/dest check on the instance? The [NAT instance guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) describes this, and may also give you additional information for configuring this.

Comment: Hey @kdgregory, thanks for your response!

I have source/dest check set to false and configured the route on the main route table as well. No difference. The strangest thing is that on the flow logs I don't see any match towards any IP other than the network interface IP and I have enabled the flow logs at the VPC level. 

I looked at the NAT instance guide, but couldn't find anything helpful there.